# rosdep installing the dependencies fails on OSX 10.10

Tags: rosdep, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to setup ros on OSX 10.10. I'm following the installation instructions given here: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source. While resolving the dependencies using this command:

`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y`

I get an `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` error while installing `collada-dom` and `opencv`. This I guess is associated with the default stdlib for clang being libc++ instead of libstdc++.

So I tried to install the dependencies of collada-dom with libstdc++. I was able to install Boost successfully but am unable to figure out how to install `pcre` with libstdc++.

Also for opencv I installed it using libstdc++ using the formula provided here, but this is just a keg-only formula. Even though I symlinked myself, rosdep isn't detecting this version.

Any help is much appreciated. Has anyone been able to get it working on OSX 10.10?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198391/rosdep-installing-the-dependencies-fails-on-osx-10.10/) by [chintak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20949/chintak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-12-02**:
I haven't had time to upgrade to 10.10 myself, so unfortunately I can't reproduce any of these issues yet.

**Comment by [chintak](https://answers.ros.org/users/20949/chintak/) on 2014-12-02**:
Hmm. Are you on Mavericks? Can I compile against 10.8 SDK on Yosemite/Mavericks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think it is as easy as changing os x sdk versions. I think the pcre problem is an issue with the provided stdlib and compiler. But without more details I doubt anyone can help without reproducing it. As for rosdep you can just skip the opencv key if you know it is installed.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1